# Can't compile C on windows 7 x64

Tags: c, windows, mingw, visual-studio-2012

I have visual studio 2012 ultimate and mingw installed on my pc. 
However, when I try to compile any program (I have only tried a simple hello world program) 
e.g when I use the visual studio cl compiler or the gcc compiler I get the error :

> cl is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. 
>        and similar for mingw-gcc.

I have visual studio installed in the default location. I have installed mingw in D:\MinGw but I have added it to the path variable. Also I have installed CodeBlocks after getting frustrated with this and my program builds and runs easily when I try that from inside CodeBlocks. I can also compile my program from inside Visual Studio by clicking on the build and run buttons.

What do I need to do to compile and run programs from the commandline in windows 7?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of running a "regular" command prompt, run the "Visual Studio command prompt". You can find a link to it in the start menu.

It's essentially the same, but it sets up for you all the environment variables you need for all the VS tools to work from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you still have a path problem.  The mingw-gcc path for example would need to be to the bin directory:

```
D:\MinGW\bin
```

in your case.  Then you should be able to run gcc.